# File Chooser - Can't Clear Folder Selection

Tags: nautilus, gtk, filemanager

How to clear selection on folder in GtkFileChooser? The shortest way I can find is by going to upper / parent directory from current directory and coming back to it.

It is annoying when we need to save a file in the current directory while accidentally selecting folder.

If it is a bug and has been reported, please give a link. If it isn't, where should I report it? Gtk+ or Nautilus?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1877754 says "Fix Released" in 2022-05-20 by they don't indicate which commit does it nor in which version it will fall, hopefully we'll auto-update at some point in the latest Ubuntu versions? (also related https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/271 but never done)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By clicking on selected folder in GtkFileChooser doesn't deselect the folder.

If you want to deselect the selected folder, instead  of simply clicking on the selected folder, click while pressing the   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.

Comment: That is soo unintuitive...   I had to search the web to figure out how to do this.